# commutant of an operator when $dim E=2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $B$ an operator on a two-dimensional Hilbert space $E$ such that $B$ is not a scalar operator and let $\mathfrak{C}$ be the commutant of $B$ (i.e. $\mathfrak{C}$ of $B$ is the set of all Operators that commute with $B$.)  If $T$ is in $\mathfrak{C}$, why there exist some complex numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $T = aB + b$ ??

Comment: Notice that $B$ is nothing but an ordinary $2\times 2$-matrix. Can you solve the question if you think in terms of matrices?

Comment: Also it should be clear that the commutant at least contains the matrices $aB+bI$. The difficulty is showing that this is everything.

Comment: Yes this is  my  problem

Comment: Hmm, I think can prove this statement for $B$'s that are in Jordan canonical form, but I don't immediately see how this is useful. I have to go now, but I can think about it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$AB-BA=0$ is a set of $4$ equations with four unknowns.

$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{12} b_{21} - a_{21}b_{12} & -a_{12} b_{11} + a_{11} b_{12} - a_{22} b_{12} + a{12} b_{22}\\
a_{21} b_{11} - a_{11} b_{21} + a_{22} b_{21} - a_{21} b_{22} & a_{21} b_{12} - a_{12} b_{21}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\
0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

The two equations coming from the diagonal are the same. This is just $tr(AB-BA)=0$.

So, three equations really. Moreover, that equation on the diagonal only has
two unknowns. Therefore it already gives you one unknown in terms of the other. Unless it is identically zero.

Case 1: The diagonal equation is identically zero. Therefore $b_{12}=b_{21}=0$. Since $B$ is non-scalar, it follows that $a_{12}=a_{21}=0$. And the space of solutions is $2$-dimensional, at most.

Case 2: The diagonal equation is not identically zero. In this case $a_{12}$ determines $a_{21}$, or the other way around. This is because only those two unknowns are in present in that equation. Having $a_{12}$ and $a_{21}$, the remaining equations express $a_{11}$ in terms of $a_{21}$ or the other way around.

Therefore the commutant has dimension $2$ at most. Since $aB+b$ has dimension $2$ that is all of it.